# Obtener y Comparar mes en SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Necesito obtener aquellos registros de la base de datos cuyo mes almacenado en una de sus columnas de dicha tabla sea igual al mes que nos encontramos actualmente.

Basicamente: *Dame todas las filas cuyo mes sea igual al mes actual. (Almaceno la fecha en la BD en timestamp)*

> **cms_accidents** - Tabla
>
> **accident_record_uploaded_at** - Columna que almacena el timestamp

*He intentado algo así... pero no me vale. Devuelve 0 filas siempre.*

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cms_accidents WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m') = DATE_FORMAT(accident_record_uploaded_at, '%m') AND accident_record_deleted_at IS NULL");
```

Comment: saludos te comento que revertí tu edición ya que colocar la respuesta en la misma pregunta no es válido, si deseas publicar tu solución eres mas que bienvenido pero en el espacio asignado para ello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo por aportar un aspecto que creo que pasaste por alto, si quieres obtener registros sobre el mes de sistema, ubicando dicho mes en el año de sistema, faltaría en esa sentencia SQL comparar por año:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cms_accidents 
WHERE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = MONTH(accident_record_uploaded_at) 
AND YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) = YEAR(accident_record_uploaded_at) 
AND accident_record_deleted_at IS NULL
```

Completándolo con tu solución, debería quedar algo así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cms_accidents 
WHERE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(accident_record_uploaded_at)) 
AND YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(accident_record_uploaded_at)) 
AND accident_record_deleted_at IS NULL
```

Como comentaba, en el caso de buscar datos por un mes concreto de un año concreto. Si tu consulta fuera sobre un "histórico" de meses de todos los años, entonces sí, no tendrías que usar **YEAR**.

Answer (score 1):

Esta sentencia SQL debería funcionarte

```
SELECT * 
FROM cms_accidents 
WHERE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = MONTH(accident_record_uploaded_at) 
AND accident_record_deleted_at IS NULL
```

Por lo que tu código quedaría así:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cms_accidents WHERE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = MONTH(accident_record_uploaded_at) AND accident_record_deleted_at IS NULL");
```